# Regex to Remove Block Comments but Keep Empty Lines?

Tags: python, regex, comments, line-breaks

Is it possible to remove a block comment without removing the line breaks with a regex?

Let's say I have this text:

```
text = """Keep this /* this has to go
this should go too but leave empty line */
This stays on line number 3"""
```

I came up with this regex:

```
text = re.sub(r'/\*.*?\*/', '', text, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

But this gives me:

```
Keep this 
This stays on line number 3
```

What I want is:

```
Keep this

This stays on line number 3
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make a slight change to your current logic and use a lambda callback as the replacement for `re.sub`:

```py
import re

text = """Keep this /* this has to go
this should go too but leave empty line */
This stays on line number 3"""

text = re.sub(r'/\*.*?\*/', lambda m: re.sub(r'[^\n]+', '', m.group()), text, flags=re.S)
print(text)
```

This prints:

```
Keep this 

This stays on line number 3
```

The replacement logic in the lambda function operates on the `/* ... */` comment block.  It strips off all characters *except* for newlines, leaving the newline structure intact while removing all other content from the intermediate comment lines.

Comment: Nice solution! I would just add `\r` in `[^\r\n]+` in case the input has Windows line endings (`\r\n` instead of just `\n`).